# 504 accessing web service with multiple replicated pods. No error with single pod

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

Im new to kubernetes, sorry in advance for any dumb questions. Im running a small k8s cluster on digital ocean. I create 2 deployment and 2 services, basically identical, with the yaml files below. I then log in to digital ocean load balancer dashboard. I change port 80 to http, and 443 to https with a letsencrypt cert for each load balancer (this creates the A records in the DO DNS). I also enable redirect http to https. (I've tried using annotations to add these settings but the service never starts... might have to make a separate issue for that?)

This works fine with 1 replica. And I can access the app. But if I increase the replicas to 2 or more, I get a 504 when accessing the web containers. Im not really sure where to get logs to see whats going wrong. Any advice would help alot.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 7767
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 7767
  selector:
    app: web
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
        image: registry.digitalocean.com/myreg/web
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7767
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: turn
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 7768
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 7768
  selector:
    app: turn
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: turn
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: turn
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: turn
    spec:
      containers:
        image: registry.digitalocean.com/myreg/turn
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        name: turn
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7768
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) and [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/)?

Comment: Hi, yes. Everything seems healthy, and in fact I can access the web service via websocket (wss) connection from a desktop application, and that works fine. Requests dont seem to be getting through to the pod level.